# Add span in top menu item with nested itens

Tags: menus, navigation

I found examples adding a class to top level itens, so we can display an arrow in menu itens with subitens, but is seems terrible to cope with the already builtin WordPress classes, can't display the arrow with current and css hover, it just ruins all states.

Is there someway to add a `<span class="arrow"></span>` within the parent `li` instead?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter:

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_add_arrow',10,4);
function wpse_add_arrow( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ){
    //Only add class to 'top level' items on the 'primary' menu.
    if('primary' == $args->theme_location && $depth ==0){
        $item_output .='<span class="arrow"></span>';
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

This assumes that you're using `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary') );` to display the menu.

---

Updated answer in response to comments. To add the `span` classes to only top-level elements which have children you need to use a custom walker:

```
class SH_Arrow_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if('primary' == $args->theme_location && $depth ==0){
            $output .='<span class="arrow"></span>';
        }
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

To use this you'll need to set the `walker` argument in `wp_nav_menu`:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
     'theme_location' => 'primary', 
     'walker'=> new SH_Arrow_Walker_Nav_Menu()
 ) );
```

Comment: Oh! I found that the span show ups in all toplevel itens, I need it to show only the ones with nested items :(

Comment: See updated answer :)

Comment: Is there someway to insert things inside the menu item? Your code puts the content right after the link: `<li id="menu-item-3344" class="etc"><a href="http://localhost/wp3/forums/">Fóruns</a><span class="arrow"></span>`

Is there someway to goes like this:

`<li id="menu-item-3344" class="etc"><a href="http://localhost/wp3/forums/">Fóruns New!</a>`

Comment: You can edit the link text on the Appearance > Menu page.

Comment: I see, I was doing this way before you solved the issue lol I think WP adds too much classes into menu, they is hard to map all states and content :(. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the prev answer here is how to detect if an item is a parent menu item without using the Walker class

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'cfw_add_arrow',10,4);
function cfw_add_arrow( $output, $item, $depth, $args ){

//Only add class to 'top level' items on the 'primary' menu.
if('primary' == $args->theme_location && $depth === 0 ){
    if (in_array("menu-item-has-children", $item->classes)) {
        $output .='<span class="arrow">arrow</span>';
    }
}
    return $output;
}
```

Please correct me if this PHP `in_array` check might fail in some situations, so far I have not had any issues with it.

Comment: your answer is much valuable than upvote.